# Casting IntPtr to int only works sometimes

Tags: c#, .net, casting, intptr

Consider this code:

```
IntPtr p = (IntPtr) (long.MaxValue); // Not a valid ptr in 32 bit, 
                                     // but this is to demonstrate the exception for 64 bit
Console.WriteLine((int)(long)p);
Console.WriteLine((int)p);
```

The second `WriteLine` throws an `OverflowException` when compiling and running on 64 bit. This is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a8d37fb(v=vs.110).aspx).

My question is: why?

When converting a pointer to an `Int32` you conceptually lose all pointer semantics, and reduce the pointer semantically to just it's integer representation. Then why throw an exception, instead of truncating the value to fit inside an integer? That would be the most sensible thing to do imho. Because if the programmer really wanted to avoid truncation at all cost, why put it into an int in the first place?

Is this design on purpose, or is this an incomplete implementation of the conversion operator?

---

I feel some clarification is necessary after reading the first comments. My question can also be read as follows:

Is there a realistic use case where you would put an `IntPtr` into an `int` and later translate it back to an `IntPtr`, such that it is still valid after that?

---

As a reply to people asking for use cases, let me give the only use case for putting an `IntPtr` into an `int` that I can come up with: Implementing `GetHashCode` for a managed wrapper object around an unmanaged object.

Comment: How is truncating a pointer ever *sensible*? If you actually wanted this, you can always do it explicitly. You should be grateful the default is to *detect* this condition and throw an exception, regardless of what you think is most aesthetically appealing on philosophical grounds. Note that the most common reason for converting a pointer is *not* to admire its bits in a sort of vacuum -- it's because eventually the value will get converted back, possibly after manipulation. Good luck with that when the value's been hosed.

Comment: You are trying to stuff a 64 pound pig into a 32 pound poke.  It overflowed the poke of course.  Casting to long merely helped shaving 32 pounds off the pig without a squeal, truncation is silent if the expression is `unchecked`.  Which it is by default, a project setting that not enough programmers change btw.  This overflow is especially common since Windows 8.1, they favored allocating memory above 4 GB.

Comment: When is a truncated pointer useful? Can you give a me a realistic use case?

Comment: @InBetween When is putting an IntPtr into an int useful?

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke: on a 32-bit platform, it's perfectly sensible. It ceases being so when your code's supposed to work on 64-bit platforms as well.

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke When converting a valid pointer to an int, you can still convert it back to a sensible pointer. A truncated pointer is nonsense, there is nothing you can do with it so the reasonable this is to disallow it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert why is that sensible. Can you give a realistic usecase where you need to put an IntPtr into an int, and later translate it back?

Comment: @InBetween Please give a reason why you would convert to an int if you're interested in the pointer interpretation.

Comment: How about pointer arithmetic, prior to .NET 4.0? `IntPtr.Add` is a fairly recent invention.

Comment: `When is putting an IntPtr into an int useful?` So you are arguing that `public unsafe static explicit operator int (IntPtr  value)` should be removed altogether?

Comment: @mjwills Yes, sort of. Either that, or make it work in all cases. Just don't throw some exception half of the time.

Comment: The behaviour is documented at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a8d37fb(v=vs.110).aspx . It works **as specified in the docs**. Now you may not **like** the behaviour, but given there is such an easy workaround (that you have identified) what is your underlying concern here?

Comment: Note that, if you compile with overflow checking on, truncating 64-bit values to 32-bit with a cast will fail even for regular integers. Truncation is not something that's *supposed* to work "in all cases". It can always be *made* to work, by explicitly masking off bits. Being explicit is a good thing, but especially when you're discarding bits of a pointer.

Comment: Ok, question: Does the `int` represent a valid pointer or, put it another way, can you get a valid pointer back from the `int` value? The answer is yes. Can you say the same in the other case? And why stop here? Following your reasoning, why is `new IntPtr(int i)` sensible?

Comment: @mjwills There is no big concern I want to express, but this thing caught me off guard and so I wanted to understand the reason behind this implementation.

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke It is hard to build something that meets **everyone's** expectations if they don't read the docs. So my guess is that the developer's chose a _reasonable_ tradeoff (one making it hard to get an incorrect pointer) and documented it. Will it make everyone happy? No. Will it protect against a certain class of stupid error? Yes. Does it have an easy workaround? Yes. Which is likely why they made the tradeoff.

Comment: @JeroenMostert So you're saying that we should be more explicit, and the implementation of this operator shouldn't be used? I could agree, but I find an explicit cast fairly explicit, and otherwise would rather have a compile error than a runtime error.

Comment: @InBetween No, that is not true. An IntPtr doesn't always fit in an int.

Comment: This operator is *perfectly safe* if your code is 32-bit, as it can never truncate. Should it always error on 64-bit? It might have, it doesn't, instead the implementers decided to allow it in case your values always happened to fit in 32-bits. (This is possible if, for example, your code is 64-bit but receives 32-bit pointer values from other processes.) I don't think you quite appreciate just how often pointers are manhandled and misconverted when you get to mixing low-level and high-level code -- both intentionally to meet some API's demands, and unintentionally.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Could you elaborate on the latter? I.e. give an example of 32-bit code where you would need to put an `IntPtr` into an `int`?

Comment: As I said -- prior to .NET 4, you would have had to convert your pointer to an `int` if you wanted to do any kind of legitimate arithmetic on it. Even now you still need the integer conversions for any kind of "illegitimate" arithmetic (like abusing alignment restrictions to stuff data in the lower bits). You could, of course, also just use an `int*`, but then you'd have to mark your code `unsafe`. Or you could use a `long` (and anticipate 64-bit), but that could be a hassle when the rest of your values are 32-bit. For more inspiration, consult almost any Win32 project written in C.

Comment: @mjwills Yes, you're saying sensible things. But not allowing to convert IntPtr to int on 64 bit altogether would be a direct improvement according to your reasoning, so no trade-off is necessary there.

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke So you are wanting a different .NET surface area on 32-bit vs 64-bit (i.e. methods that exist only when running under 32-bit)? What if the code was compiled as AnyCPU? `according to your reasoning` To be clear, my main reasoning is the **docs** define the expected behaviour, rather than "whatever I would like in my head". :)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Fair enough. So short answer: it's all because of historical reasons. Am I correct?

Comment: @mjwills Even if compiled with AnyCPU, IntPtr will have a fixed size, either 32 or 64 bits. Which one depends on several things.

Comment: If by "historical" you mean that historically, memory locations have been given sequential numbers, then yes. :-P As long as that's the case, and your language isn't completely scoured of all pointers and given only opaque references to work with, you will have this sort of discussion. Most C# developers will never encounter these issues. Those that do have little reason to complain if they get a runtime exception on a possibly unsafe pointer conversion, as they are blessed compared to their brethren in the unmanaged world. Consistency or no consistency.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yes, that, and that you "historically" could only do arithmetic on int's. That would make a decent answer to this question I think. If you care, you could summerize into an answer, and we could have this post marked solved.

Comment: It's not true that you couldn't do pointer arithmetic other than via `int` in versions of .Net prior to .Net 4. You could always use `long` with `IntPtr`, and you've always been able to use actual pointers in `unsafe` code.

Comment: @mjwills give a compile error if possible for 64 bit, or at least *always* give a runtime error.

Comment: @MatthewWatson So you're saying there is no actual reason to store pointers in `int` variables? (Because of the `unsafe` environment)

Comment: That is a valid option @ChieltenBrinke . But if they did that, someone else would complain that the behaviour wasn't what **they** expected. Ultimately **someone** isn't happy, which is why documenting the behaviour is key.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: the point is that, for 32-bit code, it was at least *reasonable* to do pointer arithmetic by converting to `int`. (There are unrelated reasons to avoid `unsafe` code, like requiring higher trust.) Of course, prudent developers wouldn't have used 32-bit types just because they knew their code was 32-bit today, but developers aren't prudent. And also obsessed with peformance. Especially the ones casting around pointers.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's true, but I was just correcting Chiel's assumption that `"historically" could only do arithmetic on int's`

Answer (score 4):

The implementation of the cast operator for `IntPtr` to `int` is as follows (from [ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/intptr.cs,d99bf6ad49979009))

```
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
    [System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionable]
    public unsafe static explicit operator int (IntPtr  value) 
    {
        #if WIN32
            return (int)value.m_value;
        #else
            long l = (long)value.m_value;
            return checked((int)l);
        #endif
    }
```

As you can see, for Windows x64 it will be explicitly using `checked` to force an exception on overflow. (And I'm very glad that it does!)

Conversely, when you cast it to a `long` first and then cast to an `int` yourself, by default it will be done `unchecked` and therefore no exception will be thrown.

I can only guess at the reason they did this, but it seems fairly obvious that truncating a pointer is almost always A Bad Thing, so they decided that the code should throw an exception if truncation happens.

Comment: "truncating a pointer is almost always A Bad Thing". If the programmer wants to put the intptr's value in a normal integer type, it's conceptually not a pointer anymore (as I argued in the OP), so you're not truncating the pointer, but an integer which happens to be derived from a pointer value. In other words, if truncating is a bad thing, why put it into an int in the first place?

Comment: @ChieltenBrinke Putting a pointer into a 32-bit int would work for 32-bit code, but the only place I can think that someone would want to do that is for interop. I agree it's dodgy, and perhaps converting an IntPtr to an `int` in 64-bit code should always throw an exception regardless of whether it would fit. However, Microsoft have decided not to make that restriction, for whatever reason.

Comment: Anyway the side-effect of this is that if you want to treat a pointer as a non-pointer, you have to cast it to a `long` first, and only then can you start throwing away bits. I guess Microsoft thought that would be safer rather than silently throwing away data. Remember, this stuff was put in some years ago when most people were running 32-bit code so it would all just work.